# Opacity with light black backgroud on children element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile web application with a screen size of **360 X 640.**
I am not able to apply a transparent /black background as shown in the figure blow behind the Buy Now button . I have used absolute and relative positioning. Can someone help me out with this? I tried to use opacity but it doesn't work as I want .

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
}

.experience {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.see-all {
  float: right;
  color: orangered;
}

.choose-form {
  background-color: rgb(246, 229, 246);
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

option {
  font-size: 10px;
}

select {
  height: 50px;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-block mx-3" style="min-width: 500px;height: 100%;">
  <div class="mt-5" style="text-align: center;padding :10px;">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zQ6pBdV/Report-1.png" alt="Report-1" border="0">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(129,254,188,0.5); position:relative ; margin-top:-90px;">
      <p><span style="float: left; margin-top:9px;color: white; ">₹999/min</span>

        <span class="see-all"> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning orange">Buy Now </button>
  </span> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I want**

[image]

**My front-end**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background div has a height of zero, setting a height will result in the transparent background becoming visible(I added `height: 70px` to the HTML):

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
}

.experience {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.see-all {
  float: right;
  color: orangered;
}

.choose-form {
  background-color: rgb(246, 229, 246);
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

option {
  font-size: 10px;
}

select {
  height: 50px;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-block mx-3" style="min-width: 500px;height: 100%;">
  <div class="mt-5" style="text-align: center;padding :10px;">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zQ6pBdV/Report-1.png" alt="Report-1" border="0">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(129,254,188,0.5); position:relative ; margin-top:-90px; height:70px;">
      <p><span style="float: left; margin-top:9px;color: white; ">₹999/min</span>

        <span class="see-all"> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning orange">Buy Now </button>
  </span> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float` it removes an element from the normal flow of the page. Because your elements inside the `<div>` with the background opacity are using `float`, the element has no height. To fix this, either set a height, or use a clearfix:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float: left;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Div 2</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
.clearfix::after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

[Here is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) explaining what a clearfix is (and why you should try to avoid using float now that there are much better alternatives available)

**Clearfix applied to your code:**

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
}

.experience {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.see-all {
  float: right;
  color: orangered;
}

.choose-form {
  background-color: rgb(246, 229, 246);
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

option {
  font-size: 10px;
}

select {
  height: 50px;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-block mx-3" style="width: 500px;height: 100%;">
  <div class="mt-5" style="text-align: center;padding :10px;">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zQ6pBdV/Report-1.png" alt="Report-1" border="0" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="clearfix" style="background-color:rgba(129,254,188,0.5); position:relative ; margin-top:-90px; padding: 23px">
      <span style="float: left; margin:0;color: white; ">₹999/min</span>
      <span class="see-all">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning orange">Buy Now </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```